# Give code limited amount of time to execute within

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a line of code in an app that looks like this:

```
string botMessage = chatterBotSession.Think(input);
```

It's querying a chat bot service and stores the response in `botMessage`. Sometimes however, the chat bot can take too long to think of a response.

Is there a way I can run the code like normal, but if it doesn't complete in one second cancel it and then run some handler that can alert the user that the service took too long?

Like, normally I might do this:

```
string botMessage = chatterBotSession.Think(input);
Console.WriteLine("The bot responded with: " + botMessage);
```

but if the bot is slow the second line doesn't get executed (fast enough). How can I limit the bot's "thinking" time to one second, and run the rest of the code (that would normally run) as soon as it completes if it was successful or run a separate bit of code to display an error message if it hasn't completed.

Comment: Is this a WinForms or WPF application? Which .Net version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the bot's service call in a Task.Run call and wait for it a predefined amount of time. It would look something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => chatterBotSession.Think(input));
    if (task.Wait(1000))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't get an answer in a timely manner");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: MSDN Ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270644(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to limit the task execution by using `CancellationTokenSource` with timeout:

```
var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
var task = chatterBotSession.Think(cancellationToken.Token);
cancellationToken.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)); // cancel after 1sec
await task;
```

In `Think` method you should add call to `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`

Comment: I don't think he has control of the Chat bot service.  Otherwise he could just build the timeout into the Think call.

Comment: He can always wrap that call into Task.Run and use the cancellation token.

Comment: Task.Run doesn't handle the cancellation itself, it just allows you to pass a token that you can check yourself.  Think is a single blocking call that sometimes takes too long, so there won't be an opportunity to check the token to cancel it once it has started.

Comment: Task.Run.Wait(timeout) might work, that will throw a timeout exception if it runs out, then he can write his error message in the handler for the timeout exception

Comment: This isn't going to work, `chatterBotSession.Think` returns a string, and only accepts a single string as input.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Bot:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TalkingBot bot = new TalkingBot();
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thinking started...");
        Console.WriteLine(bot.Think("Some input...", 2000));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And Bot itself:

```
class TalkingBot
{
    string input = null;
    int timeout = 0;
    string asyncThnikResult = null;

    public string Think(string input, int timeout)
    {
        DateTime timeLimit = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(timeout);
        this.input  = input;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(AsyncThnik));
        thread.Start();

        //wait for result, in this case 
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(asyncThnikResult))
        {
            if (timeLimit <= DateTime.Now)
            {
                throw new Exception("Timeout occured!");
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        //return result...
        return this.asyncThnikResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Do your thing async...
    /// </summary>
    void AsyncThnik()
    {
        string temp = "This value will never be returned due to timeout limit...";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeout + 1000);  //add second to produce timeout...
        this.asyncThnikResult = temp;
    }

}
```